# What is the meaning of the idiom "If it were not for..."?

Tags: grammar, mood

I have a question about mood

Note that the following sentences are same :

If I did not have money, I could not buy it

=I could not buy it **without** money

=**If it were not for** money, I could not buy it

=Since I have money, I can buy it.

I want to know forming of the expression : **If it were not for** (A)

I guess that this is **shortened** from some long clauses. Consider the
following :

I have only one cat and it is from Korea
=I have a cat, which is from Korea.

Usually we use second sentence. But it can be viewed as shortened
form of first sentence. That is, about (A) I want to know the
forming. Translation is nonsense. Especially we cannot translate "it"
If we write the sentence into complete sentence in detail, what is it ?

Thank you in anticipation.

Comment: your title question makes no sense and is unclear

Comment: ok that would be very helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *indicative mood* is used to make assertions; the *subjunctive,* to express doubt or a wish or desire, and in constructions involving a condition contrary to fact.

Indicative:  "I *have* money, therefore I *can* buy this."  "I *have* no money, therefore I *cannot* buy this."  These are clear statements of a situation and its consequence.  They may or may not be true, but they are assertions about reality.

Subjunctive:  "If I *had* enough money, I *could* (*would be able* to) buy this."  "If I *did not have* enough money, I *would be unable* to (*could not*) buy this."  These are statements about situations that are not real:  "If I had enough"--but I do not; "If I did not have enough"--oh, but I do!  Note that when the main clause is in the subjunctive, the subordinate clause is put into the conditional, to carry through the notion of a condition contrary to fact.

Lastly, the phrase you want to know about:  "If it were not for the fact that I have enough money, I would be unable . . ."  Basically what you are saying is that you do have enough, but wish to make an observation about a consequence if the situation were the reverse.

The main clause as I phrase it is cumbersome.  You could certainly shorten it to "If it were not that I have enough . . ."  You can also use a noun phrase, as in "If it were not for my large bank account . . . ," or a gerundive phrase, as in "If it were not for having lots of money, . . . ."

Answer (score 2):

the word "money" is a word that encompasses an aggregate.  Like, for example, "corn."  We would not find ourselves saying "we have a corn for dinner."  Instead, we would say, "we have corn for dinner."

So adding the "A" in front of it is incorrect, as idiomatic speech.

This is a common mistake by little children.  "How many money do you have?"..."I have a money."  These are incorrect because the word "money" is not refferant to a single object.

*edit* the edit to the original question, which destroyed the original question, rendered my response moot.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I editted my original question.